# Can not run JS code with a Laravel Blade stack

Tags: javascript, laravel

This code runs:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        function esFeatureDetect() {
            console.log('Feature detection function has been called!');
        }
    </script>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        esFeatureDetect();
    </script>
@endpush
```

The problem is that if I take the function and put it in another file (using webpack), suddenly the function is not found.

Here is what the code looks like in the external file:

```
function esFeatureDetect() {
    console.log('Feature detection function has been called!');
}
```

Webpack bundles it fine.  (I use Webpack for many other files too).

Here are the new blade directives:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/dist/js/full-feature-detect.js"></script>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        esFeatureDetect();
    </script>
@endpush
```

But I get an error saying that:

> esFeatureDetect is not defined

Why is it so?

The file is being pulled into the browser file, I can see the code in the console.  I also tried the following call:

```
window.onload = esFeatureDetect;
```

and

```
window.onload = esFeatureDetect();
```

but neither helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to use you function in the global scope you'll need to attach it to the `window` object.

```
window.esFeatureDetect = function () {
    console.log('Feature detection function has been called!');
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ross, that nailed it. But why?  Why do I need to assign it to the window just because it is coming from a different file?

Comment: @KimPrince This is simply down to scope. https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript. My wording of this might be a bit off but essentially webpack will create a bundle from your code which will be made up of one or many modules. When you define a function in this way it will only be able to the scope of that module e.g.  `function a() { function b() {}}` you would only be able to call `b();` from inside `a();`

Comment: Thanks Ross, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use asset() function?

```
<script src="{{asset('/dist/js/full-feature-detect.js')}}"></script>
```